# Concatenate automatically in vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of devices running at which machines in excel sheet.

Example `device A` runs at `machine X`, `B` runs at `Y` and another `device A` runs at `machine Z`. But sometimes the same devices are running on multiple machines.

Is it possible to concatenate to show that `A device` is running at `machine X,Z` ?

> devices|machines

```
A|X

B|Y

A|Z
```

I've tried to concatenate in excel. It works but the list is updated hourly so I need to record a macro of it. I also have to `vlookup` it into another sheet.

I want it to look like this:

> devices   | machines

```
A |  X,Z

B | Y
```

Comment: You can use Loops and arrays to achieve this, loop through the cells, split them with `|` , match the first character with previous splits and if it matches store the value in array.

Comment: since you are new, i suggest going here to ask a question. And most importantly dont forget the code! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub MakeListCol()


Dim coll As New Collection
Dim c As Range
Dim sPair() As String
Dim sVal As String
Const cSep1 = "|"
Const cSep2 = ","

For Each c In Range("A:A")   ' suppose the "A|X", "B|Y" pairs are in column A
    If IsEmpty(c) Then Exit For ' finish
    sPair = Split(c.Value, cSep1)
    If UBound(sPair) > 0 Then
        On Error Resume Next
        sVal = coll(sPair(0))
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            On Error GoTo 0
            sVal = sVal & cSep2 & sPair(1)
            coll.Remove (sPair(0))
        Else
            On Error GoTo 0
            sVal = sPair(0) & cSep1 & sPair(1)
        End If
        coll.Add sVal, sPair(0)
    End If
Next

'  here you have a list of all device-machines assignements in coll

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To coll.Count
    Debug.Print coll.Item(i)
Next

End Sub
```